# Flutter: How to add an extra ListTile to ListView manually

Tags: flutter, dart

What I want to do is to add an extra `LisTile` to the last of `ListView` but I still don't figure it out.
My current code is like this.

```
child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == 0) {
            // Add an extra item to the start
            return ListTile(
             ...
            );
          }
          index -= 1;
          final item = _items[index];

          // I want to an extra item here as well
          if (index == _items.length) {
              return ListTile();
          }

          return ListTile(
              ...
          );


        },
        itemCount: _items.length + 2,
```

I've already tried the way above, but it doesn't work. There is an error.

> Invalid value: not in range 0..4, inclusive 5

When I changed `itemCount` to `_items.length + 1`, it doesn't show the extra `ListTile` I want to add to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add to the beginning and the end as well check below

```dart
child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == 0) {
            // Add an extra item to the start
            return ListTile(
             ...
            );
          }
          if (index == _items.length + 1) {
              return ListTile();
          }

          index -= 1;
          final item = _items[index];



          return ListTile(
              ...
          );


        },
        itemCount: _items.length + 2,
```

Comment: Is there any reason?

Comment: sorry I didn't see the beginning, edited the answer now, hope it helps..

Comment: @Ooto did you check this answer well ? you should change the first check from 0 to item.length and add just to itemCount  +1

Comment: @Ooto edited this answer try this. it should add to the start and the end as well..

Comment: try this one, on your last 7th call index will be 6 and lenght()+1 = 6 as well

Answer (score 0):

your bug is here:

```dart
itemCount: _items.length + 2,
```

you should increase it by one

because you added 2 elements and for the last call you get index = list.length + 1, and then you subtract 1 from it, and you end up 1 over your length.

ex lets say your list have 5 elements, because you have

```
itemCount: _items.length + 2
```

Listview will call your func 7 times, and in 7th call your index is 6 and you are doing index =-1, which equals to 5, and 5 is over your range. (you have form 0 to 4)

Comment: As I write in the question, when I increased it by one, it doesn't show the extra item that is added to the end.

Comment: do you want to add to the beginning and end as well or only to the end ? if only end delete the first ==0 check, and add if (_items.length == index) as in my answer

Comment: As I write in the comment, I want to add to both the  start and the end..